# Find duplicates for one column with the last row group by one column in Pandas Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 4 columns in my dataframe `user` `abcisse` `ordonnee`,`time`

I want to find for each user the duplicate row with the last row of the user, duplicate row meaning two row with same abcisse and ordonnee.

I was thinking to use the df.duplicated function but i don't know how to combine it with groupby ?

```
entry = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,0,1],[1,3,-2,2],[1,2,1,3],[1,3,1,4],[1,3,-2,5],[2,1,3,1],[2,1,3,2]],columns=['user','abcisse','ordonnee','temps'])

output = pd.DataFrame([[1,0,0,1],[1,2,1,3],[1,3,1,4],[1,3,-2,5],[2,1,3,2]],columns=['user','abcisse','ordonnee','temps'])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
print (entry.drop_duplicates(['user', 'abcisse', 'ordonnee'], keep='last'))
   user  abcisse  ordonnee  temps
0     1        0         0      1
2     1        2         1      3
3     1        3         1      4
4     1        3        -2      5
6     2        1         3      2
```

Comment: Thanks it was quick !  I forgot to see that group by user was the same that to include it in the column on which to duplicate..

Comment: Yes, so I add `user` column for check duplicates, it is instead `groupby` + check duplicates.